# How to call helper method when we change any field?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I need to execute a helper method in lightning component whenever i change status field in record. 
Can anyone suggest me an idea how to call helper method when we update any record?

Comment: Can you share what have you done so far?

Comment: Hi Carlos. I have no idea how to do that. Can you just tell me how to do that. I don't need any code. Like can we override Save button where can we call lighting component?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by applying an `onchange` attribute on your field.

```
onchange={yourmethodhere}
```

Then on your JS add a function:

```
yourmethodhere: function (component, event, helper) {
// Your code here
}
```

These are the basics...

Applying the `onchange` to the field that you want to add the logic is basically the first thing you need to do. Them make sure that it points to the function in you JS and you should be able to get what you want.

**UPDATE:**

You can use [Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder) or a Trigger to get this done.

Comment: i am not using any field tag in lighting component. I am just modifying field in record level. When i try to change field in record level i need to execute a helper method form any lighting component.

Comment: The field that changes the status, it is inside a LC, correct?

Comment: No Carlos. it is not inside a LC

Comment: you use the LC only to see the record, right? (Based on what you said)
or it has other scopes?

Comment: Ok, so you want a method to be executed when a field changes the status on Lightning Experience.... you probably need to look to a Trigger or use Process Builder. Probably the second option...

Comment: Hi carlos, I know we can do that by trigger. But my question is Can't we call a lighting components helper method when a field changes?

Comment: A component is mean to do something more than just execute code/logic. Normally you call a LC from other LCs when the structure of the first LC can be utilize in several scenarios. You can use a flow perhaps, I need to know what you intend to do, but you can't call a LC from a field directly if is not inside a LC.